# Finding Eigenvalues for a boundary value problem

Tags: differential-equations, eigenvalues

I have a 10x10 linearized BVP which I can write as $$\mathbf{y}'(x) = \mathbf{A}(\omega) \mathbf{y}(x)$$ subject to boundary conditions $$\mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{0}, \quad x=0 \\ \mathbf{C} \cdot \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{0}, \quad x=1,$$ where $\mathbf{B}, \mathbf{C}$ are diagonal matrices.

Here is one such value of $A$ (with values rounded), although this depends on a set of other parameters that I'd like to explore how the eigenvalues depend on (particularly looking for stability)

```
A = SparseArray[{{{1, 2}, {1, 7}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {4, 6}, {5, 6}, {6, 5}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}} -> 1, 
    {{1, 9}, {6, 4}} -> -1, {4, 1} -> -600 ω, {{4, 2}, {4, 7}, {8, 2}} -> -300, 
    {{4, 9}, {8,9}, {10, 2},{10, 7}} -> 300, {8, 7} ->  10000 + 700 ω, {{8, 8}, {10, 10}} -> 14, {10, 9} -> -700 + 700 ω}]

yvec = Through[Array[y, 10][t]];
bcmat = DiagonalMatrix[{0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}];
bcs = Thread[Select[Join[bcmat.yvec /.t->0, bcmat.yvec /.t->1],LeafCount[#] > 1 &] == 0]
```

I'm looking for the (possibly complex) eigenvalues of $\omega$ to give a non-trivial solution to my boundary-value problem, but I get errors regarding numerical ill-conditioning when just trying to use NDSolve, e.g.

```
NDSolve[Flatten@{Thread[D[yvec, t] == A.yvec]/.ω->1, bcs}, Array[y, 10], {t, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Also, is there no tag for BVPs?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Update: This implementation is now a package called `CompoundMatrixMethod`, hosted on [github](https://github.com/SPPearce/CompoundMatrixMethod). It can be installed easily by evaluating:

```
Needs["PacletManager`"] 
PacletInstall["CompoundMatrixMethod", "Site" -> 
 "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/paclets/Repository/master"]
```

This version also includes a function `ToMatrixSystem` which converts a system of ODEs to matrix form (and linearises if necessary), including the boundary conditions. This eliminates the need to set the matrices directly, and also specifies which variable is the eigenvalue, simplifying the notation. Please use the package rather than the code below.

---

I've written an implementation of the Compound Matrix Method that suits my purposes, and so I'll put it here for other people. A good explanation of this method are available [here](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~xl/FYB-background.pdf). Basically the Compound Matrix Method takes an $n$ by $n$ eigenvalue problem of the form $$\mathbf{y}' = A(x, \lambda) \mathbf{y}, \quad a \leq x \leq b, \\ B(x,\lambda) \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{0}, \quad x=a, \\ C(x,\lambda) \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{0}, \quad x=b,$$ and converts it to a larger system of determinants that satisfy a different matrix equation $$ \mathbf{\phi}' = Q(x, \lambda) \mathbf{\phi}.$$
This removes a lot of the stiffness from the equations, as well as being able to also remove the exponential growth terms that dominate away from an eigenvalue.

The code is written for general size $n$, and I've used it for $n=10$. The first time you run the code for a particular size $n$ the general form of matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ will be calculated, for $n=10$ this takes about 3 minutes for me, after that the matrix will be cached. The matching should be independent of the choice of matching point, but you can change it in the code to check that.

```
reprules = ϕ[a_List] :> Signature[a] ϕ[Sort[a]];
minorsDerivs[list_?VectorQ,len_?NumericQ] := 
 Sum[Sum[AA[y, z] ϕ[list /. y -> z], {z, Union[Complement[Range[len], list], {y}]}], {y, list}] /. reprules

qComponents[n_?NumericQ, len_?NumericQ] := qComponents[n, len] = 
       Coefficient[Table[minorsDerivs[ii, len], {ii, Subsets[Range[len], {len/2}]}] 
       /.Thread[Subsets[Range[len], {len/2}] -> Range[Binomial[len, len/2]]], \[Phi][n]]

Evans[{λ_/;!NumericQ[λ], λλ_?NumericQ}, Amat_?MatrixQ, bvec_?MatrixQ, cvec_?MatrixQ, 
        {x_ /;!NumericQ[x], xa_?NumericQ, xb_?NumericQ,xmatch_:False}] := 
 Module[{ya, yb, ϕpa, ϕmb, valsleft, valsright, ϕpainit, ϕmbinit, posint, 
   negint, ϕmvec, ϕpvec, det, QQ, len, subsets,matchpt},
  len = Length[Amat];

  If[(xa <= xmatch <= xb && NumericQ[xmatch]), matchpt = xmatch, matchpt = (xb - xa)/2];
  If[!EvenQ[len], Print["Matrix A does not have even dimension"]; Abort[]];
  If[Length[Amat] != Length[Transpose[Amat]],Print["Matrix A is not a square matrix"]; Abort[]];
  subsets = Subsets[Range[len], {len/2}];
  ya = NullSpace[bvec];
  If[Length[ya] != len/2, Print["Rank of matrix B is not correct"];Abort[]];
  yb = NullSpace[cvec];
  If[Length[yb] != len/2, Print["Rank of matrix C is not correct"];Abort[]];
  ϕmvec = Table[ϕm[i][x], {i, 1, Length[subsets]}]; 
  ϕpvec = Table[ϕp[i][x], {i, 1, Length[subsets]}];
  ϕpa = (Det[Transpose[ya][[#]]] & /@ subsets);
  ϕmb = (Det[Transpose[yb][[#]]] & /@ subsets);
  valsleft =  Select[Eigenvalues[Amat /. x -> xa /. λ -> λλ], Re[#] > 0 &];
  valsright = Select[Eigenvalues[Amat /. x -> xb /. λ -> λλ], Re[#] < 0 &];
  ϕpainit = Thread[Through[Array[ϕp, {Length[subsets]}][xa]] == ϕpa];
  ϕmbinit = Thread[Through[Array[ϕm, {Length[subsets]}][xb]] == ϕmb];
  QQ = Transpose[Table[qComponents[i, len], {i, 1, Length[subsets]}]] /. 
     AA[i_, j_] :> Amat[[i, j]] /. λ -> λλ;
  posint = NDSolve[{Thread[D[ϕpvec,x] == (QQ - Total[Re@valsleft] IdentityMatrix[Length[QQ]]).ϕpvec], ϕpainit}, 
     Array[ϕp, {Length[subsets]}], {x, xa, xb}][[1]];
  negint = NDSolve[{Thread[D[ϕmvec,x] == (QQ - Total[Re@valsright] IdentityMatrix[Length[QQ]]).ϕmvec], ϕmbinit}, 
     Array[ϕm, {Length[subsets]}], {x, xa, xb}][[1]];
  det = Total@Table[ϕm[i][x] ϕp[Complement[Range[len], i]][x] (-1)^(Total[Range[len/2] + i]) //. reprules /. 
      Thread[subsets -> Range[Length[subsets]]], {i, subsets}];
  Exp[-Integrate[Tr[Amat], {x, xa, matchpt}]] det /. x -> matchpt /. posint /. negint]
```

For a simple 2nd order eigenvalue problem, $y''(x) + \lambda y(x) = 0, y(0)=y(L)=0$, the roots can be found analytically as $n \pi/L, n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Here the matrix $A$ is `{{0,1}, {-\[Lambda]^2, 0}}`, and the BCs are `DiagonalMatrix[{1, 0}]`:

```
Plot[Evans[{λ, λλ}, {{0, 1}, {-λ^2, 0}}, 
     DiagonalMatrix[{1, 0}], DiagonalMatrix[{1, 0}], {x, 0, 2}], {λλ, 0.1, 20}]
```

[image: Compound Matrix Method example for simple 2nd order eigenvalue problem]

Changing the boundary conditions is straight forward, so for a Robin BCs like $y(0)+2y'(0)=0$ the corresponding matrix $B$ would be `{{1, 2}, {0, 0}}`.

For the first 4th order example in the [linked notes](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~xl/FYB-background.pdf) $$\epsilon^4 y''''(x) + 2 \epsilon^2 \lambda \frac{d}{dx}\left[\sin(x) \frac{dy}{dx}\right]+y =0, \\ y(0) = y''(0) = y'(\pi/2) = y'''(\pi/2) = 0,$$ the matrices are given by:

```
A1={{0,1,0,0}, {0,0,1,0}, {0,0,0,1}, {-1/ϵ^4, -2 ω Cos[x]/ϵ^2, -2 ω Sin[x]/ϵ^2, 0}}; 
B1 = DiagonalMatrix[{1,0,1,0}]; C1 = DiagonalMatrix[{0,1,0,1}];

Evans[{ω, 1}, A1 /. ϵ-> 0.1, B1, C1, {x, 0, Pi/2}]
(* -0.650472 *)
```

And we can then vary the value of $\omega$ to see the roots:

```
 Plot[Evans[{ω, ωω}, A1 /.ϵ->0.1, B1, C1, {x, 0, Pi/2}], {ωω, 1, 3}]
```

[image: Plot of the compound matrix method determinant for a 4x4 case]

For a 10x10 example similar to my original question (that has positive eigenvalues):

```
A2 = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, -5, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-625 ω, -(125/2), 2, 
0, 0, 3, -300, 0, 300, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
0, -1.5, 1/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0}, {0, -169, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9175 + 694 ω, 0, 811, 0}, {0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 672, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3222, 
0, -709 + 694 ω, 0}};
B2 = C2 = DiagonalMatrix[{0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}];

Evans[{ω, 1}, A2, B2, C2, {x, 0, 1}]
(* 0.672945 *)
```

We can plot and see some positive eigenvalues:

```
 ListPlot[Table[{ωω,Evans[{ω, ωω}, A2, B2, C2, {x, 0, 1}]},{ωω,0.1,1,0.01}]
```

[image: Plot of the compound matrix method determinant for a 10x10 case]

And then `FindRoot` will find one:

```
 FindRoot[Evans[{ω, ωω}, A2, B2, C2, {x, 0, 1}],{ωω,0.5}]
```

The eigenfunctions can be extracted from this method if required, but I haven't coded that here. The subtraction of the dominant growing eigenvalues from $Q$ may not be suitable for all problems, but is really useful when it works. It will also use exact numbers if you give them in the original matrices, so it'll be faster if you give an approximate number.

Comment: If anyone has comments about for improving my code feel free to let me know. I was thinking that the root specification should probably be moved to the last option rather than the first (like in functions like FindRoot).

Comment: I have read the explanation of this method (in the provided link), where the 1st method (determinantal method) is actually a shooting method?

Comment: @Nobody, yes, the determinant method is a shooting method. This is a shooting method too, but the compound matrix method lifts the problem from being on a relatively unstable space of dimension $n$ (which is prone to blowing up to infinity), to one where there is more stable. The Allen and Bridges (2002) paper, https://doi.org/10.1007/s002110100365, is relatively readable regarding that.

The other benefit compared to the determinant method is that it subtracts the exponentially growing parts, which means that the value of the Evans function is order 1, rather than say 10^30.