# Eigenvalue dependent boundary conditions- mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, eigenvalues, boundary-conditions

I am dealing with an eigenvalue problem whose boundary conditions are also eigenvalue dependent.

Could anyone please comment whether Mathematica can numerically solve such a problem? For boundary condition independent of eigenvalues, I use `NDEigenSystem`.

A minimal working example is given here. The eigenvalue problem:
$$ -\frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2} +x^2 \psi = E \psi $$
with two boundary conditions:
 $$\textrm{(i) }\psi = 0 \textrm{ at }x = 0$$ and $$\textrm{(ii) }\frac{d\psi}{dx}+E^2\psi = 0 \textrm{ at } x = 1$$ needs to be solved to calculate the eigenvalues, $E$, of this operator. This might seem to be a trivial task, but please be aware of the eigenvalue-dependent boundary condition. I would be very thankful if anybody could suggest how to solve such eigenvalue problem in mathematica.

Comment: Yes it can.....

Comment: You won't get a certain answer without showing us the precise equations.

Comment: There was a question where the eigenvalue was both in the ode and was where the bc was applied:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166952/solving-this-challenging-ode/167425#167425

Comment: Have you tried using NDEigensystem?

Answer (score 3):

While we wait for anyone to use `NDEigensystem` to see whether that works for this case (I expect it does), I have a package for numerically calculating solutions of eigenvalue problems using the Evans function via the method of compound matrices, which is [hosted on github](https://github.com/SPPearce/CompoundMatrixMethod). See my [answers to other questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=compoundmatrixmethod) or the github for some more details.

First we install the package (only need to do this the first time):

```
Needs["PacletManager`"]
PacletInstall["CompoundMatrixMethod", 
    "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/paclets/Repository/master"]
```

Then we first need to turn the ODEs into a matrix form $\mathbf{y}'=\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{y}$, using my function `ToMatrixSystem` (note capital `E` is reserved, so use lower case here):

```
Needs["CompoundMatrixMethod`"]

sys = ToMatrixSystem[-ψ''[x] + x^2 ψ[x] == e ψ[x], 
       {ψ[0] == 0, ψ'[1] + e^2 ψ[1] == 0}, ψ, {x, 0, 1}, e]
```

The object `sys` contains the matrix $\mathbf{A}$, as well as similar matrices for the boundary conditions and the range of integration.

Now the function `Evans` will calculate the Evans function (also known as the Miss-Distance function) for any given value of $\lambda$; this is an analytic function whose roots coincide with eigenvalues of the original equation.

FindRoot will then find solutions for a given start point:

```
FindRoot[Evans[e, sys], {e, 1}]
 (* {e -> 9.9609} *)
```

You can see there are a whole set of positive real eigenvalues:

```
Plot[Evans[e, sys], {e, 0, 500}]
```

[image]

There are also some imaginary roots (I think just the two):

```
FindRoot[Evans[e, sys], {e, I}]
 (* {e -> 0.159709 + 1.09317 I} *)

ContourPlot[{Re[Evans[er + I ei , sys]] == 0, Im[Evans[er + I ei , sys]] == 0}, 
               {er, -3, 3}, {ei, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 30]
```

[image]