# Eigenvalues of a fourth-order ODE

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions, eigenvalues, boundary-conditions

Consider the following ODE for $y(x)$ over $x\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$ with an eigenvalue $\lambda$

$\qquad 2x\,y''''+ 4y'''=\lambda\, y''$

The boundary conditions at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ are $y'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=0$ and $y''\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\lambda y\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$.

At $x=0$ we enforce $y(0)=0$ and require $y'(0)$ to be a finite number.

How can I solve numerically for the eigenvalues (values of $\lambda$ corresponding to non-zero solutions) using Mathematica?

Comment: Have a look at `NDEigensystem`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher  It is not obvious to me that `NDEigensystem` can handle this problem, due to the appearance of the eigenvalue in one boundary condition and the finiteness of the solution as another boundary condition.

Comment: I have a package (CompoundMatrixMethod) for finding eigenvalues numerically that can cope with the eigenvalue in the boundary condition(e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197165/eigenvalue-dependent-boundary-conditions-mathematica/197257), but not the finiteness constraint. I can find eigenvalues when the fourth BC is homogeneous (e.g. $y'(0)=0$ or $y''(0)=0$ or $y'''(1/2)=0$, but not when you only wish to impose that it is finite.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem can be solved symbolically, although perhaps not with `DEigensystem`.  Instead, begin with `DSolve`.

```
s = DSolveValue[{2 x y''''[x] + 4 y'''[x] == lamda y''[x], y[0] == 0, 
    y'[1/2] == 0, y''[1/2] == lamda y[1/2]}, y[x], x] // FullSimplify
(* (16 C[2] (BesselI[0, Sqrt[lamda]] (-1 + 2 x + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[lamda] Sqrt[x]
    BesselK[1, Sqrt[2] Sqrt[lamda] Sqrt[x]]) + x (-2 + lamda BesselK[0, Sqrt[lamda]])
    Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[2, (lamda x)/2]))/(lamda^2 ((8 + lamda) 
    Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[3, lamda/4] + lamda Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[4, lamda/4])) *)
```

Next, expand the derivative of this expression about `x = 0` to determine the eigenvalues.

```
ser = (Normal@Series[D[s, x], {x, 0, 0}]) // FullSimplify
(* (8 C[2] (-4 + 2 lamda BesselK[0, Sqrt[lamda]] + BesselI[0, Sqrt[lamda]] 
   (4 + 2 EulerGamma lamda + lamda (Log[lamda/2] + Log[x]))))/
   (lamda^2 ((8 + lamda) Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[3, lamda/4] + 
   lamda Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[4, lamda/4])) *)
```

The `Log[x]` term will not be finite at `x = 0` unless its coefficient vanishes.  It is

```
(* (8 BesselI[0, Sqrt[lamda]] C[2])/(lamda ((8 + lamda) Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[3, lamda/4] + 
   lamda Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[4, lamda/4])) *)
```

Replacing `lamda` by `- z^2` allows further simplification

```
FullSimplify[coef /. lamda -> -z^2]
(* (2 BesselJ[0, z] C[2])/((-8 + z^2) BesselJ[2, z] + 2 z BesselJ[3, z]) *)
```

Clearly, the numerator vanishes at `BesselJZero[0, k]` for all nonnegative integer k, suggesting that

```
lamda -> - BesselJZero[0, k]^2
```

Unfortunately, this substitution also causes the denominator to vanish, as can be shown by evaluating it numerically for various `k`.  (`FullSimplify` cannot do the required simplification.)  The expression for `lamda` thus is plausible but not necessarily correct.

Instead, solve the original system with this expression for `lamda` assumed from the outset.  (We choose a particular value of `k` at random, because `FullSimplify` can make no headway otherwise.)

```
ss = DSolveValue[{2 x y''''[x] + 4 y'''[x] == lamda y''[x], y[0] == 0, y'[1/2] == 0, 
    y''[1/2] == lamda y[1/2]} /. lamda -> -BesselJZero[0, 17]^2, y[x], x] // FullSimplify
(* (2 x C[1] Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[2, -(1/2) x BesselJZero[0, 17]^2])/ 
   BesselJZero[0, 17]^2 *)
```

along with the warning message,

> > > Solve::ztest1: Unable to decide whether numeric quantity 2 Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[3,-(1/4) BesselJZero[0,17]^2]-1/4 BesselJZero[0,17]^2 Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[3,-(1/4) BesselJZero[0,17]^2]-1/4 BesselJZero[0,17]^2 Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[4,-(1/4) BesselJZero[0,17]^2] is equal to zero. Assuming it is.

In fact, it is equal to zero, as can be seen by evaluating it numerically.  `FullSimplify` does not know an identity to demonstrate that this expression vanishes.

Finally, take the derivative of `ss` and evaluate it at `x = 0`.

```
FullSimplify[D[ss, x]]
% /. x -> 0
(* (2 C[1] Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[1, -(1/2) x BesselJZero[0, 17]^2])/
   BesselJZero[0, 17]^2 *)
(* -((2 C[1])/BesselJZero[0, 17]^2) *)
```

demonstrating that the earlier expression for `lamda` is correct.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, the expression for 'ss' vanishes identically to zero.

Answer (score 4):

First solving

```
Clear[x, y]
sol = DSolve[2 x y''''[x] + 4 y'''[x] == lambda y''[x], y, x][[1]]
yx = y[x] /. sol
```

and then the boundary conditions

```
equ1 = (D[yx, x] /. {x -> 1/2}) // FullSimplify
equ2 = ((D[yx, {x, 2}] - lambda yx) /. {x -> 1/2}) // FullSimplify
equ3 = Limit[yx, x -> 0] // FullSimplify
equ4 = Limit[D[yx, x], x -> 0] - dy0
```

giving

```
(* (2 (-1 + BesselI[0, Sqrt[lambda]]) C[1] - 4 BesselK[0, Sqrt[lambda]] C[2])/lambda + C[4]*)
(*C[1] - 1/2 lambda (2 C[3] + C[4])*)
(*(4 C[2])/lambda^2 + C[3]*)
(*-dy0 + DirectedInfinity[-Sign[C[2]]]/lambda*)*)
```

Analyzing those results we conclude that to be feasible, the conditions should dictate **C[2] = C[3] = dy0 = 0** so we follow

```
equ10 = equ1 /. {C[2] -> 0, C[3] -> 0};
equ20 = equ2 /. {C[2] -> 0, C[3] -> 0};
M = Grad[{equ10, equ20}, {C[1], C[4]}];
equ0 = Det[M] // FullSimplify
(* -BesselI[0, Sqrt[lambda]] *)
```

and then the eigenvalues are the real roots for **BesselI[0, Sqrt[lambda]]** or

```
Plot[-BesselI[0, Sqrt[lambda]], {lambda, -150, 0}]
```

or

```
Solve[{BesselI[0, Sqrt[lambda]] == 0, lambda < 0}, lambda][[1]]

(*lambda -> ConditionalExpression[-BesselJZero[0, C[1]]^2, C[1] \[Element] Integers && C[1] >= 1]*)
```

[image]