# An ODE system easily polluted with spurious eigenvalues

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method, eigenvalues, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I tried solving the eigenvalue problem of a 1st-order ODE system (see the code below)
with `NDEigenvalue`. 
(One option I found in it seems to be `PDEDiscretization` that descretizes the spatial part, i.e., the only part here.) But I don't know how to tune it to improve the partially wrong result. The right boundary is actually at infinity and here I use `Rcutoff` instead.

```
f = 20; b = 2; 
eps0 = 1*^-10; l = -2; R = 2; Rcutoff = 1.0 Min[6 R, 16/Sqrt[f]]; Nless = 50;
A[l_, B_, r_] := l/r + f/2 r;
Fop1[y_, l_, pm_] := I (-D[y, r] + pm A[l, f, r] y);
variables = {α, β};
lhs = {Fop1[β[r], l + 1, -1] + b α[r], 
   Fop1[α[r], l, 1] - b β[r]};
bc = DirichletCondition[
   Table[component@r == 0, {component, variables}], True];
Re@NDEigenvalues[{lhs, bc}, variables, {r, eps0, Rcutoff}, Nless]
```

The **analytical solution**, based on some algebraic theory, is simply given by $\{-b,\pm\sqrt{b^2+2f},\pm\sqrt{b^2+4f},\pm\sqrt{b^2+6f},\cdots\}$, of which the *absolute values*, in incresing order, have a pattern 1,2,2,2,... (*number of same absolute values*).  Numerically it is

${-2., \pm6.63325, \pm9.16515, \pm11.1355, \pm12.8062, \pm14.2829, \pm15.6205, \pm16.8523, \pm18., \pm19.0788, \pm20.0998, \cdots}$

However, the above `NDEigenvalue` code gives

${\pm1.99995, \pm6.63407, \pm9.16917, \pm11.1455, \pm12.825, \pm13.6968, \pm14.3126, \pm15.6619, \pm16.9056, \pm18.0631, \pm18.6132, 
\pm19.1502, \pm20.1722, ...}$

Not quite accurate and **there are spurious eigenvalues sneaked in** (e.g. $\pm13.6968, \pm18.6132$) and the pattern becomes 2,2,2,2,....

(For this type of equation, there is a folklore theorem or purported fact that discretization can yield correct results although it usually doubles the solution set and hence a pattern 2,4,4,4,... `NDEigenvalue` probably uses finite element method? Here it unexpectedly looks to double only the first eigenvalue.)

***But in any case, some values sneaked in are obviously wrong.***

Any method other than `NDEigenvalues` is certainly welcome as well.

### Update:

As mentioned in the comments, one can play with two `MeshOptions`. Indeed, the accuracy can be improved. But unfortunately, it is robbing Peter to pay Paul as far as I've tried. Always spurious or copied values unexpectedly sneak in somewhere.

```
Re@NDEigenvalues[{lhs, bc}, variables, {r, eps0, Rcutoff}, Nless, 
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions"
-> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001, "MeshOrder" -> 2}}}}]
```

---

The real system I want to play with is the following 4 coupled equation system. ***It has exactly the same problem and equation type as the above oversimplified one.*** Therefore, I kinda thought posting a new question might not be a good idea. One can just add/replace these a few lines (and switch between using `m0` or `m1` in `lhs`). The analytical solution for `m0` is $\{\pm\sqrt{m_0^2+b^2},\pm\pm\sqrt{m_0^2+b^2+2f},\pm\pm\sqrt{m_0^2+b^2+4f},\pm\pm\sqrt{m_0^2+b^2+6f},\cdots\}$ where $\pm\pm$ means two copies. For `m1`, no analytical solution, but the similar pattern will emerge when increasing `R`.

```
m0[R_, r_] = 1.0; m1[R_, r_] := 1.0/R (Exp[r/R] - 1);
variables = {α, β, γ, δ};
lhs = {Fop1[δ[r], l + 1, -1] + b γ[r] + m1[R, r] α[r], 
   Fop1[γ[r], l, 1] - b δ[r] + m1[R, r] β[r], 
   Fop1[β[r], l + 1, -1] + b α[r] - m1[R, r] γ[r], 
   Fop1[α[r], l, 1] - b β[r] - m1[R, r] δ[r]};
```

---

With all respect to bbgodfrey's answers, I wish to mention ***some drawbacks*** in order to draw any possible alternative answers. (1) Usually such defferentiation-substitution generates redundant solutions. If one has *a priori* exact solutions, fine. Otherwise, this could be not so straightforward to identify. (2) It **doesn't work for the `m1` case** (no analytical solution) because one cannot recover the structure of a valid eigenvalue equation.

---

**About boundary condition**: For 1st order ODE, b.c. at both ends are somehow redundant. One end is enough in my naive understanding. But it doesn't seem to matter much in my personal tries of this problem. What I specified in the code above is zero-Dirichlet at both ends. The LEFT b.c. can be easily seen from asymptotic analysis at $r=0$. And the RIGHT b.c. at infinity should be zero from two considerations (1. some background knowledge of finite `f` effect. 2. It must vanish at least for the divergent `m1` case, which is the interested one.). So one can choose whether to keep them all or anything else.

Comment: I suggest adding the code for obtaining the exact solution, that'll make your post more convincing.

Comment: @xzczd Updated.

Comment: Did you try the different `Method` options for `NDEigenvalues` already? Some might give better results than others for your problem.

Comment: Adding an option like `Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" ->
{"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}}}` impoves the accuracy dramatically. Basically, you have to tell the numerical algorithm how exact it should be. The first eigenvalue is still "doubled". though.

Comment: About the folklore part: What?!? Such a statement would definitely depend on the type of discretization...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks for your info. That introduces 2 extra spurious values around 20 and 28 even down to `"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.00001`. And switching between `MeshOrder` of 1 and 2 seems to only rob Peter to pay Paul. BTW, do you know how to set the overall number of mesh points?

Comment: Is the actual b.c.s placed at infinity? If so, you'd better mention it in the body of the question.

Comment: @xzczd Sorry, I should've mentioned. Updated.

Comment: Can you give a link explaining / deriving the analytical solution you have?

Comment: @user21 Sure, check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Ladder_operator_method).

Comment: @bbgodfrey Terribly sorry. Let correct the typo.

Comment: These four first-order equations definitely can be converted to a pair of second-order equations or to a single fourth-order equation, barring degeneracies.  Eliminate `α[r]` and `γ[r]` first.

Comment: I'm away from Mathematica for a week, but I have a package to use the Evans function to solve eigenvalue problems numerically, available at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155079/finding-eigenvalues-for-a-boundary-value-problem/

Comment: @KraZug Thanks! That will be so nice if you're going to try it or even post an answer later.

Comment: Yeah, I mostly posted to remind myself when I get back.

Comment: @xzczd The problem is hard, because `NDEigenvalues` does not handle the regular singularity at `r == 0` well, and cannot accommodate the correct boundary condition, `DirichletCondition[α[r] == 1/2 I r (-2 + λ) β[r], r == eps0]` there. Additionally, solutions are noisy near `r == Rcutoff`, although the noise is not obvious on plots over `{eps0, Rcutoff}`.  Using a larger `WorkingPrecision` probably would help, but `NDEigenvalues` does not accept it as an option.  In other words, the problem is hard, because `NDEigenvalues` lacks the flexibility to accommodate the problem.

Comment: I'm unclear what the boundary conditions should be at the two ends, is it as @bbgodfrey suggests in his answer and the above comment at the left and decaying at infinity?

Comment: @KraZug Yes, for 1st order ODE problem, b.c. at both ends are redundant. One end is enough in my naive understanding. I didn't mention this because it doesn't seem to matter in my tries. What I specified in the code is zero-Dirichlet at both ends. The left b.c. can be easily seen from asymptotic analysis at $r=0$. And the right b.c. at infinity should be zero from two considerations (1. some background knowledge of finite `f` effect. 2. It must vanish at least for the divergent `m1` case, which is the interested one.). So one can choose whether to keep them all or anything else.

Comment: @KraZug But in any case, I'd rather not specify something like $\alpha$ at both ends while nothing for $\beta$. This looks a bit weird to me.

Comment: Well, one of the cases that I've used the Evans function to solve for is localised waves, where you want the functions to decay in the infinite limits. At which point when you write the system in matrix form, $\mathbf{y}'=\mathbf{A} \mathbf{y}$, you need $\mathbf{A}$ to tend to a constant in the limit. Your set of equations don't do that here, the matrix A blows up.

Comment: Do you mind writing the equations in LaTeX form?

Comment: @KraZug Sorry, not sure what you mean by localized waves and blowing up of $A$. My case is surely spatially confined and decays well at large enough $r$.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Hmm… as to the b.c., my opinion is similar to OP i.e. b.c.s at right boundary should be enough to determine the solution, but `DirichletCondition[
   Table[component@r == 0, {component, variables}], r = Rcutoff]` seems not to help here…

Comment: @xzczd Determining the eigenvalues of the original problem (two first-order equations) bears a strong similarity to determining the eigenvalues of the Bessel ODE, which has a regular singularity at `r == 0`, and where a boundary condition is needed at `r == 0` and at `r  == Rcutoff`.  Also, see my symbolic solution to the original problem, which requires one boundary condition at each end.

Comment: @xzczd What a pity! No further response to your generous bounty... Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: At least there exist answers so my 250 won't go with wind 囧.

Comment: @xzczd, I'm a little late for your bounty, but hopefully my new answer is helpful.

Comment: @xiaohuamiao, I would like to use this set of equations as an example in my package. Is there a reference where they come from at all?

Comment: @KraZug They are not yet in the literature, I think. But please feel free to use in your package. I'll let you know when I publish them somewhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The additional problem added to the end of the question can be solved in a similar manner.  Begin with

```
variables = {α[r], β[r], γ[r], δ[r]}; 
lhs = {Fop1[δ[r], l + 1, -1] + b γ[r] + m0[R, r] α[r], 
       Fop1[γ[r], l, 1] - b δ[r] + m0[R, r] β[r], 
       Fop1[β[r], l + 1, -1] + b α[r] - m0[R, r] γ[r], 
       Fop1[α[r], l, 1] - b β[r] - m0[R, r] δ[r]}
```

and other quantities as in the question.  Then, eliminate `α[r]` and `γ[r]`:

```
eqe = List @@ Eliminate[Thread[Flatten[{D[(lhs - λ variables)[[1]], r], 
    D[(lhs - λ variables)[[3]], r], lhs - λ variables}] == 0], 
    {α[r], α'[r], γ[r], γ'[r]}] // Most
(* {β''[r] == -35 β[r] + β[r]/r^2 + 100 r^2 β[r] - λ^2 β[r] - β'[r]/r, 
    δ''[r] == -35 δ[r] + δ[r]/r^2 + 100 r^2 δ[r] - λ^2 δ[r] - δ'[r]/r} *)
```

The equations for `β[r]` and `δ[r]` are decoupled and identical in form, so they must have the same eigenvalues.  The symbolic solution for `β[r]` is

```
solβ = β[r] /. DSolve[{eqe[[1]], β[0] == 0}, β[r], r] // First
(* (E^(5 r^2) C[2] LaguerreL[1/40 (-35 - λ^2), -1, -10 r^2])/r *)
```

Eigenvalues are given by setting the first argument of `LaguerreL` to a negative integer.

```
Solve[1/40 (-35 - λ^2) == -n - 1, λ] // Flatten
(* {λ -> -Sqrt[5] Sqrt[1 + 8 n], λ -> Sqrt[5] Sqrt[1 + 8 n]} *)
```

Numerical values can be obtain by

```
bcβ = DirichletCondition[β[r] == 0, True];
eqβ = eqe[[1]] /. Equal -> Subtract /. λ -> 0;
NDEigenvalues[{eqβ, bcβ}, β[r], {r, eps0, Rcutoff}, Nless/2, Method -> 
    {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" -> 
    {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 1/1000, "MeshOrder" -> 2}}}}];
Sqrt[-%]
(* {2.23607, 6.7082, 9.21954, 11.1803, 12.8452, 14.3178, 15.6525, 16.8819, 
    18.0278, 19.105, 20.1246, 21.095, 22.0227, 22.9129, 23.7697, 24.5967, 
    25.3969, 26.1725, 26.9258, 27.6586, 28.3725, 29.0689, 29.7489, 30.4138, 
    31.0645} *)
```

**Addendum: `m1` Eigenvalues**

As noted in comments below, the method used above for `m0` cannot be applied to `m1`, because the second-order ODEs for `β[r]` and `δ[r]` are not in a form acceptable to `NDEigenvalues`.  Nonetheless, progress can be made with a bit of human intervention.  With `m0` replaced by `m1` in the equations above and

```
bc = DirichletCondition[Thread[variables == 0], True]
(* DirichletCondition[{α[r] == 0, β[r] == 0, γ[r] == 0, δ[r] == 0}, True] *)
```

both the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenfunctions can be computed and plotted with

```
ss = NDEigensystem[{lhs, bc}, variables, {r, eps0, Rcutoff}, Nless, 
    Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" 
    -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 1/500, "MeshOrder" -> 2}}}}];
ev = First@ss // Chop
ef = GraphicsGrid[Map[Plot[Evaluate@ReIm@#, {r, eps0, Rcutoff}, 
    PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Medium] &, ss[[2]], {2}]]
(* {-2.00352, 2.00352, 2.00683, -2.00683, 6.6257, -6.6257, 6.64552, -6.64552, 
    9.15861, -9.15861, -9.17763, 9.17763, 11.13, -11.13, 11.1483, 11.1483, 
    -12.8016, 12.8016, -12.8195, 12.8195, 14.2446, -14.2446, -14.2791, 14.2791, 
    14.2966, -14.2966, 14.3307, -14.3307, -15.6175, 15.6175, -15.6349, 15.6349, 
    16.8502, -16.8502, 16.8673, -16.8673, -17.9987, 17.9987, -18.0157, 18.0157, 
    -19.0782, 19.0782, -19.0952, 19.0952, 20.0662, -20.0662, -20.1, 20.1, 
    -20.117, 20.117} *)
```

Rather than review all 200 plots here, consider plots of `β[r]` for `λ == 2.00352` and `λ == 2.00683`,

```
Plot[Evaluate@ReIm@ss[[2, 2, 2]], {r, eps0, Rcutoff}, PlotRange -> All, 
    ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {r, β}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, 16]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate@ReIm@ss[[2, 3, 2]], {r, eps0, Rcutoff}, PlotRange -> All, 
    ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {r, β}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, 16]]
```

[image]

The second eigenfunction, a sawtooth, almost certainly is spurious.  Identifying such sawtooth results can be automated by determining whether the values at adjacent mesh points near the maximum or minimum of one of the curves have opposite signs.  **Update:** The following function does so.

```
fsaw[n_] := Module[{vg = Im[n[[2]] /. r -> "ValuesOnGrid"], 
    gg = Flatten[n[[2]] /. r -> "Grid"], vm},
    vm = Flatten[Part[#, Ordering[vg, -1]] & /@ {gg, vg}]; 
    If[Abs[Last[vm]] < 10^-6, vm = Flatten[Part[#, Ordering[vg, 1]] & /@ {gg, vg}]]; 
    First[vg[[Flatten[Position[gg, Last[Nearest[gg, First[vm], 2]]]]]]] Last[vm] < 0]
```

In all, there are eight spurious solutions in the fifty computed.  Delete the corresponding eigenvalues and plot the rest.

```
Position[fsaw[#] & /@ ss[[2]], True]
(* {{3}, {4}, {21}, {22}, {27}, {28}, {45}, {46}} *)

Delete[ev, %];
ListPlot[{Select[%, # > 0 &], Select[%, # < 0 &]}, ImageSize -> Large,
    PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798],
    AxesLabel -> {r, λ}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, 16]]
```

[image]

These values are qualitatively similar to those for `m0`, although smaller in magnitude.

**Addendum: Multiplicity of `m1` Roots**

Essentially all the comments following the answer by [KraZug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/23105/krazug) focus on why pairs of `m1` roots are closely spaced instead of being single roots of multiplicity two, as in the `m0` case, discussed at the beginning of this answer.  Some insight can be obtained by attempting to reproduce the `m0` computation for `m1`.  Begin by replacing `m0` or `m1` by an arbitrary function `m` in the four ODEs.

```
lhs = {Fop1[δ[r], l + 1, -1] + b γ[r] + m[R, r] α[r], 
       Fop1[γ[r], l, 1] - b δ[r] + m[R, r] β[r], 
       Fop1[β[r], l + 1, -1] + b α[r] - m[R, r] γ[r], 
       Fop1[α[r], l, 1] - b β[r] - m[R, r] δ[r]};
```

and perform the following manipulations.

```
eqtst = Subtract @@@ (List @@ 
    Eliminate[Thread[Flatten[{D[(lhs - λ variables)[[1]], r], 
        D[(lhs - λ variables)[[3]], r], lhs - λ variables}] == 0], 
        {α[r], α'[r], γ[r], γ'[r]}] // Most);
Collect[%, D[m[2, r],r], Simplify];

Collect[First[eqtst]/(-4 + λ^2 - m[2, r]^2), D[m[2, r],r], Simplify];
eqβ = % /. %[[1]] -> Collect[%[[1]], {β[r], β'[r], β''[r]}, Simplify]
(* (36 - r^-2 - 100*r^2 + λ^2 - m[2, r]^2)*β[r] + β'[r]/r + β''[r] + 
   ((-((-1 + 10*r^2)*(λ - m[2, r])*β[r]) + (2 - 20*r^2)*δ[r] + r*(-λ + m[2, r])*
   β'[r] - 2*r*δ'[r])*D[m[2, r],r])/(r*(-4 + λ^2 - m[2, r]^2)) *)

eqδ = Collect[(Last[eqtst] - First[eqtst] (λ + m[2, r])/(-4 + λ^2 - m[2, r]^2))/2,
    D[m[2, r],r], Simplify]
(* (36 - r^-2 - 100*r^2 + λ^2 - m[2, r]^2)*δ[r] + δ'[r]/r + δ''[r] + 
   (((-2 + 20*r^2)*β[r] + (-1 + 10*r^2)*(λ + m[2, r])*δ[r] + 2*r*β'[r] + r*
   (λ + m[2, r])*δ'[r])*D[m[2, r],r])/(r*(-4 + λ^2 - m[2, r]^2)) *)
```

As expected, replacing `m` by `m0` reproduces the decoupled second order ODEs near the beginning of this answer.  In fact, replacing `m` by any constant, including `m1[Infinity, r]`, equal to zero, still produces multiplicity-two eigenvalues, although the numerical values are slightly different.  On the other hand, non-constant `m` shifts the multiplicity-two eigenvalues and splits them by a small amount due to the coupling.  The symmetries of the two ODEs are indicated by

```
Simplify[(eqδ /. {β[r] -> 0, Derivative[_][β][r] -> 0}) == 
    (eqβ /. {δ[r] -> 0, Derivative[_][δ][r] -> 0} /. {β -> δ, λ -> -λ})]
(* True *)
```

and for the coupling terms

```
Simplify[(eqδ /. {δ[r] -> 0, Derivative[_][δ][r] -> 0} /. {β -> δ}) == 
    -(eqβ /. {β[r] -> 0, Derivative[_][β][r] -> 0})]
(* True *)
```

In principle, these equations could be solved by, first, setting the coupling terms to zero and solving the resulting uncoupled equations, and then by estimating the magnitude of the coupling terms for the corresponding eigenfunctions, which give the size of the splitting.  However, for the problem at hand, the numerical method given in the main part of this answer (or the answer by  [KraZug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/23105/krazug)) is more straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the answer again! May I ask a stupid question? Does this method work for the `m1` case in my post? It seems that we cannot recover the structure of a characteristic equation after the substitution. We get many different $\lambda$-power terms.

Comment: @xiaohuamiao  I encountered the same problem myself last night and do not see a way around it.  There may be other approaches, however.  For instance, use the original approach in your question, and discard the bad answers, which you can recognize from looking at the corresponding eigenfunctions.  The method described [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html#3518691) also might work when combined with an explicit shooting method.

Comment: Your answers give workable solutions anyway, so +26 :) . BTW I suggest moving all symbolic solutions to one answer and numeric to the other so the 2 answers will be more distinct.

Comment: @xzczd  Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

`NDEigenValues` handles the pair of first-order equations in the question much more accurately, when it is converted into a single second-order equation.

```
eqe = Eliminate[Thread[Flatten[{D[(lhs - λ variables) // First, r], 
    lhs - λ variables}] == 0], {α[r], α'[r]}] // First
(* β''[r] == -36 β[r] + β[r]/r^2 + 100 r^2 β[r] - λ^2 β[r] - β'[r]/r *)
```

where `λ` is the desired eigenvalue and `variables` has been redefined as

```
 variables = {α[r], β[r]};
```

but other quantities are as define in the question.  The differential operator to be used in `NDEigenValues` is

```
eqβ = eqe /. Equal -> Subtract /. λ -> 0
(* 36 β[r] - β[r]/r^2 - 100 r^2 β[r] + β'[r]/r + β''[r] *)
```

and the quantity eliminated by `λ -> 0` above is `- λ^2 β[r]`.  Hence, the corresponding eigenvalue of the new differential  operator is `- λ^2`.  Now, redefine

```
bc = DirichletCondition[β[r] == 0, True]
```

corresponding to `bc` in the question but with `α[r]` eliminated.

```
NDEigenvalues[{eqβ, bc}, β[r], {r, eps0, Rcutoff}, Nless/2, Method -> 
    {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" -> 
    {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 1/1000, "MeshOrder" -> 2}}}}];
Sqrt[-%]
(* {2., 6.63325, 9.16515, 11.1355, 12.8062, 14.2829, 15.6205, 16.8523, 
    18., 19.0788, 20.0998, 21.0713, 22., 22.891, 23.7487, 24.5764, 25.3772, 
    26.1534, 26.9072, 27.6405, 28.3549, 29.0517, 29.7321, 30.3974, 31.0484} *)
```

and, of course, their negative values as well.  Note that this process has acquired one extra eigenvalue, `λ == 2`, which is not valid in the original pair of equations, because `(lhs - λ variables)[[1]]` is degenerate for this value of `λ`.

For completeness, the eigenvalues and engenfunctions also can  be solved symbolically:

```
solβ = β[r] /. DSolve[{eqe, β[0] == 0}, β[r], r] // First
(* (E^(5 r^2) C[2] LaguerreL[1/40 (-36 - λ^2), -1, -10 r^2])/r *)
```

Now, expand `solβ` at `r == Infinity`.

```
Series[solβ, {r, Infinity, 1}] // Normal
(* r^(-(λ^2/20)) (-((2^(21/10 - λ^2/40) 5^(1/10 - λ^2/40) E^(5 r^2) C[2])/
   (r^(14/5) (36 + λ^2) Gamma[1/40 (-36 - λ^2)])) + 
   ((-5)^(1 + 1/40 (36 + λ^2)) 2^(3 + 1/40 (36 + λ^2))
   E^(-5 r^2) r^(4/5 + λ^2/10) C[2])/((36 + λ^2) Gamma[1/40 (36 + λ^2)])) *)
```

which is exponentially large except when `Gamma[1/40 (-36 - λ^2)]` is infinite; i.e., when its argument is a negative integer.

```
Solve[1/40 (-36 - λ^2) == -n - 1, λ] // Flatten
(* {λ -> -2 Sqrt[1 + 10 n], λ -> 2 Sqrt[1 + 10 n]} *)
```

**Addendum: Brute Force Approach**

Because the ODEs in the question collectively are second-order, the code in the question actually specifies too many boundary conditions, although `NDEigenvalues` does not object.  Using the correct number, for instance,

```
bc = DirichletCondition[α[r] == 0, True];
```

works about as well as `bc` in the question, producing mostly good eigenvalues but some spurious ones too.  (The same is true for `bc = DirichletCondition[β[r] == 0, True];`.)  A better boundary condition can be obtained by solving the ODEs asymptotically for small `r`.

```
Collect[AsymptoticDSolveValue[Thread[lhs == λ variables], variables, 
    {r, 0, 2}], {C[1], C[2]}, Simplify]
(* {(I (4 + r^2 (16 + λ^2)) C[1])/(2 r^2 (-2 + λ)), 
    (r - 1/4 r^3 (16 + λ^2)) C[2] + C[1] (1/r + 1/4 r (16 + λ^2) - 
    1/8 r^3 (576 + 52 λ^2 + λ^4) + 1/8 r (36 + λ^2) (-4 + r^2 (16 + λ^2)) Log[r])} *)
```

This result is higher order than necessary, so we reduce the order to

```
Series[%, {r, 0, -1}] // Normal
(* {(2 I C[1])/(r^2 (-2 + λ)), C[1]/r} *)
```

This is, of course, the solution singular at `r == 0`, so the desired boundary condition must exclude it.  (In response to a comment below, `{α[r], β[r]}` near `r == 0` must be orthogonal to the expression above; i.e., `{α[r], β[r]}.{(2 I C[1])/(r^2 (-2 + λ)), C[1]/r}` must be equal to zero.  The resulting equation can be simplified in various ways, eliminating the constant `C[1]`.  One is the following.)

```
Solve[variables.% == 0, α[r]][[1, 1]] /. Rule -> Equal
(* α[r] == 1/2 I r (-2 + λ) β[r] *)
```

Inserting this into `NDEigenvalues` yields various errors, the most important of which is

> NDEigenvalues::fembdcc: Cross-coupling of dependent variables in ... is not supported in this version.

So much for that idea.  Instead, try a brute force approach.

```
eq = Thread[0 == (lhs - λ variables)];
spm = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq, α[eps0] == 1/2 I eps0 (-2 + λ) β[eps0], β[eps0] == 1}, 
    β, {r, eps0, Rcutoff}, {λ}];
Table[Quiet@FindRoot[spm[λ][Rcutoff] // Chop, {λ, -Sqrt[b^2 + 2 f n] - 1/10,
    -Sqrt[b^2 + 2 f n] + 1/10}, WorkingPrecision -> 30], {n, 0, 24}] // 
    Flatten // Values
```

which reproduces the analytical values obtained earlier to about eight significant figures in just a few minutes.  Positive eigenvalues can be obtained analogously.  Of course, having good guesses for `FindRoot` helps greatly. The eigenvalues can be found without those good guesses but much more slowly.

Now, one might suppose that the boundary condition `α[eps0] == 0` would be as effective as `α[eps0] == 1/2 I eps0 (-2 + λ) β[eps0]` for `eps0 == 10^-10`.  Not so.  Even for a single eigenvalue, Mathematica ground away for several minutes, gradually devouring most of my 16 GB memory, before I aborted the calculation.  This gives credence to my observation in a comment above that this problem is very sensitive to boundary conditions.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Do you mind if I update an a bit more realistic version? The current one is a bit oversimplified in some sense.

Comment: @xiaohuamiao  As a matter of good practice on this site, adding minor additions to a question is fine, but significantly different material should be included in a new question.  The boundary between these two is, of course, ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I decided to include that part here. I am definitely very grateful for your answer. Please check my update if you are interested.

Comment: Er… can you explain a bit more about the line `Solve[variables.% == 0, α[r]][[1, 1]] /. Rule -> Equal`? I think the straightforward way to exclude the singularity at $r=0$ is setting `C[1]` to `0`?

Comment: @xzczd  `C[1]` does not appear in the ODEs, only in the approximate solution near `r == 0`, so setting it to zero does not yield a useful boundary condition for the complete solution.  I have added a parenthetical explanation to my answer, which I hope you find useful.

Comment: Hmm… but I think the b.c. can be deduced in a more straightforward manner?: `Solve[Simplify@Map[r # &, Thread[lhs == λ variables], {3}] /. r -> 0, {α[0], β[0]}]`
, then we obtain `{α[0] -> 0, β[0] -> 0}` i.e. the one in the question.

Answer (score 7):

This is an answer based on the Evans function approach, which sets up an analytic function $D(\lambda)$, roots of which correspond to the eigenvalues of the original equations. I also use the compound matrix method to convert the ODE system into a larger system that is less stiff to integrate in general. Explanations can be found (for instance) [here](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~xl/FYB-background.pdf), [here](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~jitse/panda10.pdf) and [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1874575X0280039X).

This is all implemented via my package, `CompoundMatrixMethod`, which is available on my [github page](https://github.com/SPPearce/CompoundMatrixMethod) or can be installed via the PacletServer:

```
Needs["PacletManager`"] 
    PacletInstall["CompoundMatrixMethod", 
    "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/paclets/Repository/master"]
```

Load the package and copy the code from the question:

```
Needs["CompoundMatrixMethod`"]

f = 20; b = 2; eps0 = 1*^-10; l = -2; R = 2; Rcutoff = 
 1.0 Min[6 R, 16/Sqrt[f]]; Nless = 50;
A[l_, B_, r_] := l/r + f/2 r;
Fop1[y_, l_, pm_] := I (-D[y, r] + pm A[l, f, r] y);
variables = {α, β};
lhs = {Fop1[β[r], l + 1, -1] + b α[r], Fop1[α[r], l, 1] - b β[r]};
bc = DirichletCondition[Table[component@r == 0, {component, variables}], True];
eigs = Chop@NDEigenvalues[{lhs, bc}, variables, {r, eps0, Rcutoff}, Nless];
actualeigs = N@Flatten@{-2, Table[{-Sqrt[b^2 + 2 n f], Sqrt[b^2 + 2 n f]}, {n, 1, 30}]};
```

First we convert the system from a set of ODEs into matrix form, $\mathbf{y}'=\mathbf{A} \mathbf{y}$, using the provided function (this works on the set of ODEs directly, rather than having to be written in the `NDEigenvalues` syntax):

```
sys1 = ToMatrixSystem[Thread[lhs == λ {α[r], β[r]}], 
       {α[r0] == 1/2 I r0 (-2 + λ) β[r0], α[r1] ==  0}, {α, β}, {r, r0, r1}, λ];
```

(As an aside, I see very little difference if I just put `α[r0]==0` as the left hand BC).

Now we can use the function `Evans` in order to calculate the Evans function for a specific value of $\lambda$ (e.g. $\lambda= 2$):

```
Evans[2, sys1 /. r0 -> 0.001 /. r1 -> 2]
(* 0. + 4.96983*10^12 I  *)
```

We can then plot this function as $\lambda$ changes. Here for $-10\leq \lambda \leq 10$, highlighting the eigenvalues found above via NDEigenvalues:

```
tab1=Table[{λ, Im@Evans[λ, sys1 /. r0 -> eps0 /. r1 -> 2]}, {λ, -10, 10, 0.1}];
Show[ListLinePlot[tab1], ListPlot[{#, 0} & /@ eigs, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Evans function plot 1]

You can see that there is a root at $\lambda=-2$, but $\lambda=2$ is nowhere near.

Moving further to the right:

```
tab2=Table[{λ, Im@Evans[λ, sys1 /. r0 -> eps0 /. r1 -> 2]}, {λ, 9, 14, 0.1}];
Show[ListLinePlot[tab2], ListPlot[{#, 0} & /@ eigs, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Evans function plot 2]

```
tab3=Table[{λ, Im@Evans[λ, sys1 /. r0 -> eps0 /. r1 -> 2]}, {λ, 13, 18, 0.05}];
Show[ListLinePlot[tab3], ListPlot[{#, 0} & /@ eigs, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Evans function plot 3]

By the time you get to $\lambda>18$ the agreement doesn't hold as well, for this value of `r1`:

```
tab4=Table[{λ, Im@Evans[λ, sys1 /. r0 -> eps0 /. r1 -> 2]}, {λ, 17, 22, 0.05}];
Show[ListLinePlot[tab4], ListPlot[{#, 0} & /@ eigs, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Evans function plot 4]

Increasing the value of `r1` regains the accuracy at the far end:

```
tab5=Table[{λ, Im@Evans[λ, sys1 /. r0 -> eps0 /. r1 -> 3]}, {λ, 17.8, 22, 0.05}];
Show[ListLinePlot[tab5], ListPlot[{#, 0} & /@ eigs, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Evans function plot 5]

This method can be applied to your second sets of differential equations:

```
m0[R_, r_] = 1; m1[R_, r_] := 1/R (Exp[r/R] - 1);
variables = {α, β, γ, δ};
lhsm0 = {Fop1[δ[r], l + 1, -1] + b γ[r] +  m0[R, r] α[r], Fop1[γ[r], l, 1] - b δ[r] + m0[R, r] β[r], 
   Fop1[β[r], l + 1, -1] + b α[r] - m0[R, r] γ[r], Fop1[α[r], l, 1] - b β[r] - m0[R, r] δ[r]};
lhsm1 = {Fop1[δ[r], l + 1, -1] + b γ[r] +  m1[R, r] α[r], Fop1[γ[r], l, 1] - b δ[r] + m1[R, r] β[r], 
   Fop1[β[r], l + 1, -1] + b α[r] - m1[R, r] γ[r], Fop1[α[r], l, 1] - b β[r] - m1[R, r] δ[r]};

sysM0 = ToMatrixSystem[Thread[lhsm0 == λ Through[variables[r]]], 
 {α[r0] == 0, α[r1] == 0, γ[r0] == 0, γ[r1] == 0}, variables, {r, r0, r1}, λ];
sysM1 = ToMatrixSystem[Thread[lhsm1 == λ Through[variables[r]]], 
 {α[r0] == 0, α[r1] == 0, γ[r0] == 0, γ[r1] == 0}, variables, {r, r0, r1}, λ];
actualeigsm0 = N@Flatten@{Table[{-1, 1}*Sqrt[m0[R, r]^2 + b^2 + 2 n f], {n, 0, 30}]};
```

Now the Evans function can be calculated for both the m0 and m1 cases:

```
tab6M0 = Table[{λ, Evans[λ, sysM0 /. r0 -> eps0 /. r1 -> 1]}, {λ, 0.01, 7, 0.05}];
tab6M1 = Table[{λ, Evans[λ, sysM1 /. r0 -> eps0 /. r1 -> 1]}, {λ, 0.01, 7, 0.05}];
Show[ListLinePlot[{tab6M0, tab6M1}, PlotLegends -> {"m0 case", "m1 case"}], 
 ListPlot[{#, 0} & /@ actualeigsm0, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Evans function plot 6]

```
Chop@FindRoot[Evans[λ, sysM1 /. r0 -> eps0 /. r1 -> 2], {λ, 2.05}]
(* λ -> 2.00352 *)
```

It should be noted that the Evans function has a double root at points where the original eigenvalue has multiplicity two, so `FindRoot` won't find these points.

We can use `FindMaximum`, but `PeakDetect` on a list of points is faster and more likely to find all of them:

```
tab7M1=Table[{λ, Evans[λ, sysM1 /. r0 -> eps0 /. r1 -> 3]}, {λ, 6, 25, 0.01}];
Most@Select[tab7M1[[All, 1]] PeakDetect[tab7M1[[All, 2]]], # > 0 &]

(* {6.64, 9.17, 11.14, 12.81, 14.29, 15.63, 16.86, 18.01, 19.09, 20.11, 21.08, 22.01, 22.9, 23.76, 24.59}  *)
```

You could refine these further by using `FindMaximum` on these starting points. These double roots are the same as bbgodfrey found, to a reasonable precision anyway.

As discussed in the comments below, for the `M1` case these are actually two separate, distinct roots for each point, not a double root. This is in contrast to the `M0` case, where they are actually a double root. Increasing the accuracy via `WorkingPrecision` allows us to check on this, as the double root appears to be two nearby roots at lower values of precision (or smaller values of $r1$).

```
tab8M0 = Table[{λ, Evans[Rationalize@λ,  sysM0 /. r0 -> eps0 /. r1 -> 
 2,  WorkingPrecision -> 30]}, {λ, 6.7, 6.715, 0.001}];
ListPlot[{tab8M0, {{actualeigsm0[[4]], 0}}}, Joined -> {True, False}, 
    PlotLegends -> {"m0 case", "actual m0 eigenvalue"}, AxesLabel -> {"λ", "D(λ)"}]
```

[image]

```
tab8M1 = Table[{λ, Evans[Rationalize@λ, sysM1 /. r0 -> eps0 /. r1 -> 2,  WorkingPrecision -> 30]}, {λ, 6.61, 6.65, 0.001}];
ListLinePlot[tab8M1, AxesLabel -> {"λ", "D(λ)"}]
```

[image]

You do need to check that the value of `r1` is large enough too, as they get inaccurate in the same way as the first system of equations, and still wonder if there is a better way to describe the end condition.

Comment: Very nice analysis (+1).  The `m0` case rigorously has double roots.  Do you believe that the `m1` case also rigorously has double roots, or merely pairs of roots that are very close?  If the former, there may be a way to prove it symbolically, as I did for the `m0` case.  I looked for an `m1` proof a while back but could not find one.  What are your thouights?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks. I just did the calculation and the Evans function suggests two roots at 6.7 ish and at 14.3 ish. I'll zoom in and post at some point

Comment: Hmm. I get two very close roots for the `m0` case too (6.70818 and 6.70822 with this choice of `r0` and `r1`). Whereas for the `m1` case they are 6.62567 and 6.64552. So they are separated by different orders of magnitude.

Comment: What happens when `WorkingPrecision` or its equivalent is increased in your program (apart from a much slower computation)?

Comment: @bbgodfrey, increasing the precision helps with the `m0` roots. Setting it to 30 gives me one root in a plot where I had two before, so it does look like a double root now. Obviously takes longer though.

Comment: Whereas the two roots for the `m1` case stay separated at 6.62570 and 6.64552. And now I have to go, but I'll check back tomorrow/Monday.

Comment: @bbgodfrey @KraZug Sorry, I didn't see your comments until now. The $\pm$-pattern can be analytically shown for any `m`. While indeed, the double multiplicity is lost for `m1` and should asymptotically recover as `R`$\rightarrow\infty$. But I don't know any clear or simple enough argument to understand this multiplicity lifting. Do you have any comments?

Comment: @xiaohuamiao The `m0` equations decouple into two identical sets of two equations each.  The `m1` equations can be split into the same two sets, but a small coupling term exists between the two sets.  This weak coupling term splits the eigenvalue pairs.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks. Yes, I am also thinking along your decouple approach to understand this. Is that coupling term kind of $\mathrm{d}~m(r)/\mathrm{d}r$? That'll easily make sense.

Comment: @xiaohuamiao  Yes, but I would need to do more analysis to obtain details, and I do not have time now.  Sorry.

Comment: @xiaohuamiao, Yes, as $R->\infty$ the two roots appear to come together into a double root. Your function `m1` does not approach `m0` in the limit though, so they do stay different.